# how can I list all the available gcc CFLAGS for optimization?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

how can I get a list of all the available optimization flags and their parameter values? Something like this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html but on the command line

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gcc --help=optimizers`, but it doesn't display values.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc --help=optimizers` displays a list of all optimization flags with a short description

`gcc -Q -Oi --help=optimizers` indicates for optimization level i which optimization flag is enabled or disabled.